# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'tabel' HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my case the web server returns HTTP Status 500, see full stack below.

Error occurs in method `editWorker` when a method returns a view

```
 @RequestMapping(value=("/worker/edit/{workerId}"), method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String editWorker(@PathVariable("workerId") Long workerId, Model model) {
            Worker worker = workerService.getWorkerById(workerId);
            model.addAttribute(worker);
            return "db_editor"; //error occurs here
        }
```

If you do not use spring tags when working with a 2nd form (.. modelAttribute="tabel" ..), then there is no error.

Tell me please, what's wrong?

jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<div id="editor">
    <div id="f_ed">
        <sf:form method="post" action="/db_editor/worker/add" modelAttribute="worker">
            <sf:hidden path="id"/>
            <fieldset>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><sf:label path="fam">First name</sf:label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="fam" size="30"/><br/>
                            <sf:errors path="fam" cssClass="error" />
                        </td>
                        <td>Табель</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><sf:label path="imj">Last name</sf:label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="imj" size="30"/><br/>
                            <sf:errors path="imj" cssClass="error" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><sf:label path="otch">Middle name</sf:label></td>
                        <td><sf:input path="otch" size="30"/><br/>
                            <sf:errors path="otch" cssClass="error" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Commit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </sf:form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab_ed">
        <sf:form method="post" action="/db_editor/tabel/add" modelAttribute="tabel">
            <sf:input path="d" type="date" />
            <sf:input path="d_type" size="2"/>
            <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Add">

        </sf:form>
    </div>
    <c:if test="${!empty workerList}">
        <div id = "r_ed">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>BD</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="worker" items="${workerList}">
                    <s:url value="db_editor/worker/edit/${worker.id}" var="edit_url" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>${worker.fam}</td>
                        <td>${worker.imj}</td>
                        <td>${worker.otch}</td>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${worker.dbirth}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" /> </td>
                        <td><a href="${edit_url}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="db_editor/worker/delete/${worker.id}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

controller:

```
import ..

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/db_editor")
public class DBEditorController_test {
    private WorkerService workerService;
    private TabelService tabelService;

    @Inject
    public DBEditorController_test(WorkerService workerService, TabelService tabelService) {
        this.workerService = workerService;
        this.tabelService = tabelService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWorkers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("worker", new Worker());
        model.addAttribute("tabel", new Tabel());
        model.addAttribute("workerList", this.workerService.listWorker()); 

        return "db_editor";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/worker/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addWorkerFromForm(Worker worker) {
        workerService.addWorker(worker);
        return "redirect:/db_editor";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/worker/delete/{workerId}")
    public String delWorker(@PathVariable("workerId") Long workerId) {
        workerService.deleteWorker(workerId);
        return "redirect:/db_editor";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value=("/worker/edit/{workerId}"), method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editWorker(@PathVariable("workerId") Long workerId, Model model) {
        Worker worker = workerService.getWorkerById(workerId);
        model.addAttribute(worker);
        return "db_editor";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tabel/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOneDayForTabel (Tabel tabel) {
        tabel.setWorker( workerService.getWorkerById( 2L ) );
        tabelService.addTabel( tabel );
        return "redirect:/db_editor";
    }
}
```

model:

Worker.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workers")
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fam")
    private String fam;

    @Column(name = "imj")
    private String imj;

    @Column(name = "otch")
    private String otch;

    @Column(name = "dbirth")
    private Date dbirth;

/*getters and setters*/
}
```

Tabel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tabel")
public class Tabel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "d")
    private Date d;

    @Column(name = "d_type")
    private String d_type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="worker_id")
    private Worker worker;

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Full StackTrace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp'.

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp'.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:680)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:232)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:243)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.TilesJspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/db_editor.jsp'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:906)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_005ftemplate_jsp._jspService(main_005ftemplate_jsp.java:223)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/db_editor.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:232)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:337)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:211)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag.doEndTag(RenderTag.java:220)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_005ftemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005finsertAttribute_005f0(main_005ftemplate_jsp.java:271)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_005ftemplate_jsp._jspService(main_005ftemplate_jsp.java:159)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'tabel' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.db_005feditor_jsp._jspx_meth_sf_005finput_005f3(db_005feditor_jsp.java:630)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.db_005feditor_jsp._jspx_meth_sf_005fform_005f1(db_005feditor_jsp.java:587)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.db_005feditor_jsp._jspService(db_005feditor_jsp.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:945)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:679)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:673)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:337)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:211)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag.doEndTag(RenderTag.java:220)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_005ftemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005finsertAttribute_005f0(main_005ftemplate_jsp.java:271)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_005ftemplate_jsp._jspService(main_005ftemplate_jsp.java:159)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit method at your controller - `editWorker` - is not adding a `tabel` attribute to your model. Actually any of them are doing that but all are redirecting to the same view. So you need to add that model property at your methods, the same way you are doing at `getWorkers`.

However my advice is you should write methods annotated with [@ModelAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) to add those properties by default, so that they are going to be part of the model always. If any of your request mapping method add them they are going to override those default ones.

```
@ModelAttribute ( "worker" )
public Worker setWorkerToModel(  )
{
  return new Worker();
}

@ModelAttribute ( "tabel" )
public Tabel setTabelToModel(  )
{
  return new Tabel();
}
```

Then you can remove the below lines from your `getWorkers` method.

```
model.addAttribute("worker", new Worker());
model.addAttribute("tabel", new Tabel());
```

Comment: Because properties in the model are only available for the current request, as they are thought to be used to with the view. Every time you make a request the model is initialised and it is going to be empty. You need to add the properties again. That is what `@ModelAttribute` does. Your methods are not adding the property `tabel` to the model but the view you are returning need it, only `getWorkers`. Take a look to the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Comment: I realized, to make my example you need to add a `model.addAttribute("tabel", new Tabel());`to the `editWorker` method. Thanks again!